# Call Method - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm basically trying to get information from another activity. Therefore i would need to call the activity. I use;

```
Adduser adduser = new AddUser();
```

but when i add it, the application keeps force closing? any ideas?

MainActivity;

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

 //AddUser adduser = new AddUser(); // HERE

   // private Realm realm;
   // private RealmConfiguration realmConfig;
Button btnadd;
ListView listuser;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  //  RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
   // Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
    //getNames();

    //Add User Button
    btnadd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    listuser = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listUser);
   // adduser.txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, list);
    listuser.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Button Event
    btnadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v == btnadd) {
                Intent addUser = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddUser.class);
                startActivityForResult(addUser,1);
            }
        }
    });
}
/*void getNames()
{
    list.add(adduser.txtName.getText().toString());
}*/
@Override
protected  void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        adapter.add(data.getStringExtra("name"));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
}
```

AddUser:

```
public class AddUser extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btnback, btnsave;
EditText txtName, txtEmail, txtPhone, txtAddress;
String n1;
int no1;
Realm realm1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.adduser);
   // Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(this);
    //EditText
    txtName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtEmail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    txtPhone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);
    txtAddress=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
    //Button
    btnback =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
    btnsave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    //Button Event
    btnback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v == btnback){
                Intent main = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(main);
            }
        }
    });

    btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v == btnsave) {

                Intent result = new Intent();
                result.putExtra("name",txtName.getText().toString());
                setResult(RESULT_OK, result);

                Log.v("Name", txtName.getText().toString());
                Log.v("Email", txtEmail.getText().toString());
                Log.v("Phone", txtPhone.getText().toString());
                Log.v("Address", txtAddress.getText().toString());
//main.list.add(txtName.getText().toString());
                //UPDATE
                /*realm1.beginTransaction();
                //Saves the input data
               User user = realm1.createObject(User.class);
               user.setName(txtName.getText().toString());
               user.setAddress(txtAddress.getText().toString());
               user.setEmail(txtEmail.getText().toString());
               n1 = txtPhone.getText().toString();
               no1 = Integer.parseInt(n1);
                //COMMIT
               realm1.commitTransaction();
               */
                Toast.makeText(AddUser.this, "User has been added.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //Start Activity
                Intent save = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(save);

            }
        }
    });
}

}
```

LOG:

```
03-31 09:38:26.030 2831-2831/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.example.scott.addressbook, PID: 2831
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.scott.addressbook/com.example.scott.addressbook.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                 at com.example.scott.addressbook.MainActivity.getNames(MainActivity.java:51)
                                                 at com.example.scott.addressbook.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
03-31 09:38:26.060 941-941/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 941: eglCreateSyncKHR(1237): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
```

I've noticed this:
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method      'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Null object?

I've searched google and everyone is saying that's the way to do it? little bit confused on something simple lol. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post your logcat output, specifically the stacktrace from the crash?

Comment: sure will get the log now - and I'm basically making a 'Address Book' and i want to show the user's input (their name), and then show it in a listview. The AddUser is the class which allows the user to enter their name.

Comment: possibly error comes due to this line of code 'adduser.txtName.getText()'  in 'getNames()' method. did u initialize 'adduser.txtName' somewhere ?

Comment: @KapilRajput maybe... if I add 'List.add("test") in the 'getNames' method it works on the listview, but i'm trying to show the user's input, if thats understandable? and so i'm trying to grab it from the class 'AddUser' and the txtName is the name of the input text on the .xml where the user can type their name. thats why i thought .txtName.getText().toString(); would grab the data that i'm after.

Comment: It seems `AddUser ` is an `Activity`. It is not recommended to instantiate an `Activity` manually.

Comment: @shhp oh! so how would i get the listview to show the users input from another activity? (Sorry i'm new to this)

Comment: @ScottB first try  to initialize input text object like this adduser.txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextID);  before performing 'getText()' from it

Comment: @GHC - sorry forgot to tag you for the LogCat.  I've just added the initialize input text object, but its still force closing the application.

Comment: @ScottB, post Adduser class

Comment: @HirenPatel I have :)

Comment: @ScottB, show me code of Adduser class

Comment: @HirenPatel i meant Activity :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to get the user's input from `AddUser`.

Firstly, in the `OnClickListener` of the button, use `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity`:

```
btnadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == btnadd) {
            Intent addUser = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddUser.class);
            startActivityForResult(addUser, 1/* It can be any number you want*/);
        }
    }
});
```

Then in `AddUser` when the user finishes inputting, call:

```
Intent result = new Intent();
result.putExtra("name", txtName.getText().toString());
setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
```

Finally, override `onActivityResult` in `MainActivity`:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        adapter.add(data.getStringExtra("name"));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks!, but the listview still doesnt show anything... I will post the 'AddUser' show you what code i've got.

Comment: You don't have to start `MainActivity` again in both click listener in `AddUser`. Just call `finish`.

Comment: oh nice thanks, thats alot easier to change activities! but the txtName still doesnt show on the listview on MainActivity, but no longer force closes the application